# jsoup 1.8.2 + android, NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/applet/Applet;

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Trying to get a html parser working on android. But I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`. How can I resolve this?

Output:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/applet/Applet;
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.Session.setAppletInstance(Session.java:88)
    at org.jsoup.Connection$Method.<clinit>(Connection.java)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Request.<init>(HttpConnection.java:369)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Request.<init>(HttpConnection.java:352)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:64)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:37)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. As you can see, there is a com.trend.iwss.jscan..... Folder inside the jar archive. This is added by our trendmicro webscanner. Downloaded the jar directly and jsoup is working.
So don't download your resources when trendmicro is around the corner ;).